# When trying to connect Intel Edison BLE to CSR bluetooth dongle on pi I am getting disconnected immediately

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, intel, intel-edison

I have done pairing of Intel Edison and pi bluetooth dongle successfully but whenever I try to connect pi from Edison I always get.
Connected Yes
Connected No

I am using bluetoothctl to connect

Answer (score 0):

Try flashing an older version of the firmware. The problem seems to be with the recent update of Edison firmware.

The flashing should be done manually because, as far as I know, the wizard can only install the latest version (if you are using Windows, follow 32bit instruction on Intel website). If you found some easier way using the wizard, please share it. Thanks.